# SQL Server CTE - SELECT after UPDATE using OUTPUT INSERTED

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've seen a few posts on using CTE (WITH) that I thought would address my issue but I can't seem to make it work for my specific use case.  My use case is that I have a table with a series of records, and I need to pull some number of records AFTER a small update has been made to them.

i.e.
- retrieve records where a series of conditions are met
- update one or more columns in each of those records
- return the updated records

I know I can return the IDs of the records using the following:

```
WITH cte AS 
( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM msg 
  WHERE guid = 'abcd' 
  AND active = 1 
  ORDER BY created DESC )
UPDATE cte SET active = 0 
OUTPUT INSERTED.msg_id 
WHERE guid = 'abcd'
```

That nicely returns the msg_id field.  I tried wrapping all of that in a `SELECT * FROM msg WHERE msg_id IN ()` query, but it fails.

Anyone have a suggestion?  For reference, using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the data that you need by just adding all columns that you want. `INSERTED` contains all columns, not just the ones written to. You can also output columns from the `cte` alias. Example:

```
OUTPUT INSERTED.SomeOtherColumn, cte.SomeOtherColumn
```

Comment: Using OUTPUT INSERTED.* did it for me exactly.

Answer (score 3):

```
    CREATE TABLE #t (msg_id int)
   ; 
    WITH cte AS 
    ( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM msg 
      WHERE guid = 'abcd' 
      AND active = 1 
      ORDER BY created DESC )
    UPDATE cte SET active = 0 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.msg_id INTO #t
    WHERE guid = 'abcd'

    SELECT *
    FROM #t
```

Comment: Is there a syntax issue?  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'cte'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.  (FYI, the line number might be off, I added a 'use' statement to make sure the right database was used, your other newlines were preserved)

Comment: What does this accomplish? It selects the same data, just with an unnecessary temp table.

Comment: The "unnecessary" temp table allows the poster to use the list of ids in a join syntax against other tables if desired; different way to skin a cat.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, also very helpful.  Wish I could select two answers.